# C++ File I/O and Pointers

Tags: c++, file, header

I tried to create a program that uses an input file 'cardList.txt' that contains:

```
Schmidt, Helga
Alvarez, Ruben
Zowkowski, Aaron
Huang, Sun Lee
Einstein, Beverly
```

and I wanted to sort this alphabetically by last name.

main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "insertsortFunct.h"
using namespace std;

int main(void){
    ifstream inData;
    ofstream outData;
    const int listSize = 5;
    char cardList[listSize][25];
    instruct();
    openFile(inData, outData);
    buildList(cardList, inData);
    inData.close();
    sortList(cardList, listSize);
    cout << endl << "Your list is sorted" << endl;
    writeFile(cardList, outData);
    outData.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I defined these functions in a separate file:

```
#include "insertsortFunct.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void instruct(void){
    cout << "The program insertSort.cpp reads the file, cardList.txt " <<
        "into an array and" << endl;
    cout << "sorts the array using the selection sort algorithm." << endl;
    cout << "The sorted array is written to a file named cardList.srt." <<
        endl;
}

void openFile(ifstream& inputFile, ofstream& outputFile){
    inputFile.open("cardsList.txt");
    if(!inputFile.is_open())
        exit(1);
    outputFile.open("cardsList.srt");
    if(!outputFile.is_open())
        exit(1); 
}

void buildList(char (*array)[25], ifstream& inputFile){
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        inputFile >> array[i];
}

void sortList(char (*list)[25], int length){
    int firstOutOfOrder, location;
    char temp[25];
    for (firstOutOfOrder = 1; firstOutOfOrder < length; firstOutOfOrder++){
        location = firstOutOfOrder;
        while ( location > 0 && list[location - 1] > list[location]){
            temp[25] = list[location][25];
            list[location][25] = list[location - 1][25];
            list[location - 1][25] = temp[25];
            location--;
        }
    }
}

void writeFile(char (*array)[25], ofstream& outputFile){
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        outputFile << array[i];
}
```

However my program only prints the `instruct();` statements and nothing else appears to happen. This program is supposed to a create a file cardList.srt with the sorted list and that does not appear in my directory after compiling.

Comment: What's the return code? I think maybe openFile cannot find `cardsList.txt` file and just quits.

Comment: Yeah. You should check whether the input file (cardsList.txt) is correctly read. I created a project and add your code into it. Compiled successfully, and run ok. With your input data, here is the content of the cardsList.srt file (not inlucde double quotes), "Schmidt,HelgaAlvarez,RubenZowkowski,"

Comment: @DucPhan That's what I got too. I had the wrong input file name. Thanks guys. Now I have to figure out how to not delete the full names and have them actually sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either inputFile.is_open() or outputFile.is_open() return false and hence exit() is called.